# Enviar arquivos via rsync definindo usuario e grupo

Tags: linux, ssh

Tenho o seguinte script que envia arquivos de uma pasta local para um servidor remoto:

```
rsync -Crav --exclude 'storage' --exclude 'error_log' --exclude 'database.php' --progress --partial --rsh='ssh -p1150' /home/user/Projects/project-local/* root@77.11.333.22:/home/user/www/project-remote
```

Queria saber se existe a possibilidade de definir que os arquivos e pastas irao chegar lá com o dono e grupo dos arquivos 'user10' (exemplo).
Se sim, queria saber também como dizer que a pasta e arquivos dentro de 'vendor' tera outro grupo e dono diferente dos outros já definidos.
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Da para fazer o que você está querendo se você rodar o `rsync` a partir da máquina de destino como root (`sudo`), preservando owner e group da origem:

```
sudo rsync -Crav user@origem:/dir/de/origem /dir/de/destino
```

Para resolver o problema da segunda pergunta, mude o ownership dos arquivos dentro de vendor antes do `rsync` rodar.